# Error al Crear Vista Parcial

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Intentando hacer una vista parcial en ASP.NET con C#, me lanza el siguiente error, cabe destacar que intente hacerlo de distintas formas y me sigue marcando el mismo error, es la primera vez que me pasa con una vista y no tengo idea del porque, ya que si existe el objeto Modelo.

**¿Como puedo resolverlo?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcBackBolsaTrabajo.Models.EntrevistaIdiomaModel>

@foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombreCand) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apellidoCnad)
    </li>}
```

Controlador

```
namespace MvcBackBolsaTrabajo.Controllers
  {
    public class EntrevistaIdiomaController : Controller
     {
         IdiomaDAO m_idiomasDAO = new IdiomaDAO();
         EntrevistaIdiomaDAO m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO = new EntrevistaIdiomaDAO();

    // GET: EntrevistaIdioma
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Todos());
    }


    //Detalle

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        EntrevistaIdiomaModel entrevistaIdiomaModel = m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Obtener(id);

        return View(entrevistaIdiomaModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Notificacion()
    {
        ViewBag.Notificacion = m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.TodosXFecha();

        return View();
    }
```

Modelo

```
  namespace MvcBackBolsaTrabajo.Models
   {
   public class EntrevistaIdiomaModel
     {
    public int EntrevistaIdiomaID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nombre")]
    public string nombreCand { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Apellidos")]
    public string apellidoCnad { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fecha")]
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("C.Auditiva")]
    public string comprencionAuditivaCal { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("E.Oral")]
    public string expresionOralCal { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("E.Escrita")]
    public string expresionEscritaCal { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Comentarios")]
    public string comentarios { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Vacante")]
    public string vacante { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Recomendación")]
    public string recomendacion { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Idioma")]
    public int IdiomasID { get; set; }

    public IdiomaModel Idioma { get; set; }


}
```

}

Comment: agrega tu controlador y el modelo que estás usando :D

Comment: ya los agregue :P

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

Creo que debe ser:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item.nombreCand) @Html.DisplayFor(item.apellidoCnad)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return View(m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Todos());
```

te está regresando una lista nula, ni siquiera vacía.

En ese método trata de hacer algo como:

```
public IEnumerable<EntrevistaIdiomaModel> Todos()
{
    var result = new List<EntrevistaIdiomaModel>();
    //.. tu código de selección de datos
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la vista donde insertas la vista parcial (que me imagino es `Index`) debes aprovechar que ya mandaste el modelo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Todos());
}
```

y volver a mandarlo a la vista parcial:

```
@Html.Partial("_NotificacionInglrd", Model)
```

o

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_NotificacionInglrd.cshtml", Model)
@* Por si requieres la ruta completa *@
```

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` occurre solamente cuando intentas acceder a un objecto que no tiene referencia en memoria. En otras palabras: que esta vacio.

Esta parte del codigo es la origina el problema:

```
 return View(m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Todos());
```

El metodo `Todos()` esta retornando `null` por lo que cuando intentas recorrer la colleccion en la vista te lanza el error.

Si quieres evitar que ocurra el error cuando el metodo todos retorne `null` puedes utilizar el operador [Null coalescing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
return View(m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.Todos() ?? new List<EntrevistaIdiomaModel>());
```

Claro, lo mejor seria arreglar el metodo `Todos()` para que no retorne null si no encuentra datos.

Comment: Solo una corrección: `null` no indica que esté vacío, sino que no hay ninguna referencia en memoria. Un elemento vacío tiene referencia a un espacio en blanco pero que está ahí.